# Angular 8: Creating a custom horizontal bar chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular8

Hi I need to make a custom horizontal bar chart like the one in the following image, but I kinda don't know how I should start and what library I should use.

Features:

- Labels should be where the black bars are, but with a Title and a subtitle.
- OnClick on objects.

Does anyone here have any experience with something similar?

Would really appreciate some advise.

Thanks!

[image: Horizontal Bar Chart]

Comment: Welcome to SO. The simplest would be to search the web first for "Angular charts". Sometimes you need to add a version like 6 or 8 to get answers/results for the new Angular syntax. Here is something I found: https://www.js-tutorials.com/angularjs-tutorial/angular-6-chart-tutorial-using-chart-js/

Comment: look https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/706

Answer (score 0):

You may use ng2-charts library which is powerful library for build charts.
Here you can find example of code for horizontal bar chart: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpd3ce

Line `public lineChartType = 'horizontalBar';` define type of your chart.

In html part you should add such code:

```
<canvas baseChart width="400" height="400"
    [datasets]="lineChartData"
    [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions"
    [colors]="lineChartColors"
    [legend]="lineChartLegend"
    [chartType]="lineChartType"  -- chart type ('horizontalBar' in your case)
    [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
```

Full documentation you can find here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

`ng2-charts` supports `onClick` event. Example here: https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/LineChart

Comment: getting error : Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.

Comment: Karthic G, you should create new question and show code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

**indexAxis**: The base axis of the chart. 'x' for vertical charts and 'y' for horizontal charts.

```
 public barChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'bar'>['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    indexAxis: 'y', // <---- set *indexAxis* to 'y'
  };
```